# PHP-REGEX - Multiple Choice Type

Tags: php, css, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 2. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway"
```

What I want to do is to have an output like this and store each question to a `div`:

```
1. What is love? 
a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 

2. What is love? 
a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
```

As of the moment, I created this made-up code for regex (still a newbie, sorry!)

```
$str = "1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 2. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway"
$repl = preg_replace('#(\d+:.*?)(?=\d+:|$) *#', "$1", $str);
echo "<div>$repl</div>";
```

And the output is this and it's stored on a single `div`:

```
1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 2. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
```

I'm confused on how to separate each question and how to put a `div` on each choice... can anyone give some advice on what should I do?

Comment: You should change the way you store and / or generate your data, mixing questions and answers in one string will only lead to more problems in the future.

Comment: So, it is much better to do this?
$str = "1. Question"
$str_c = "a. 1 b. 2 c. 3 d. 4" and then do a preg_replace?

Comment: No, an array (or object) with a key for the question and a key for the answer that would contain an array with answers. Structured data is much easier to handle.

Comment: Sorry about that... thank you for the effort in teaching me! I forgot the power of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` like this:

```
$str = "1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 2. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway";

print_r(preg_split('/(?=[a\d]+\.)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
Array
(
    [0] => 1. What is love?
    [1] => a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
    [2] => 2. What is love?
    [3] => a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
)
```

`(?=[a\d]+\.)` is a lookahead that splits when followed by `number or letter a` plus a DOT.

Comment: I should read the manual more often and refer on the related functions... thanks a lot for the information!

Comment: I have a question... can I substr() index[1] and separate "a.", "b.", "c.", "d." or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You mean you want to split `index[1]` into 4 different array elements?

Comment: Yes, that could be one of the options I want to do because I want to insert it to the database.

Comment: You can then use: `preg_split('/(?=[a-d\d]+\.)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: I'd like to thank you a lot for always giving effort on answering my questions!

Comment: I have follow-up question... when I will insert it to the db, what should I do so that it could determine the question and the choices. I'll use    regex right?

Comment: You can put a simple logic in code. If split element starts with a number and dot then it is a question otherwise it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is always coherent.

AFAIK, you can solve this using PHP [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php).
ForEach question (1 ... ?) you can reformat the text to add the div you want

Comment: thank you for mentioning tokenizer, I will look up on that, I guess it will be discussed soon might as well read it in advance!