# PHP - Regex - preg_split()

Tags: php, regex

My php code goes like this:

```
$str = "1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 2. What is love 1.1? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway";

echo "<pre>";
print_r(preg_split('/(?=[\d]+\.)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
echo "<pre/>";
```

And the output is:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 
        [1] => 2. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
    )
```

I'm trying to solve this problem that I discovered. And the problem is when my $str is like this: `$str = "1. What is love 1.1? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway`

I'm getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1. What is love 
    [1] => 1.1? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 
    [2] => 2. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
)
```

I don't want "1.1" to be on the index[1], I want it to stay on index[0].

I've tried tweaking the pattern which I'm using in `preg_split()` but I'm failing on what I want to achieve...

Can anyone give some advice on what should I do?

Comment: Please give a clear-cut input and output.

Comment: Sorry about that... I now updated my inputs and outputs.

Comment: Is this really that different from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197066/php-regex-multiple-choice-type?

Comment: I apologize about that, I believe that my understanding with the rules is not that good... this will not happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **negative lookahead** to make sure there is no digit following DOT:

```
print_r(preg_split('/(?=\d+\.(?!\d))/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
Array
(
    [0] => 1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
    [1] => 2. What is love 1.1? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
)
```

Comment: first of all, my deepest thanks sir! you're a life saver, you helped me earlier on my previous activity! I should strive more!

Answer (score 1):

Here you could use boundary `\B` which matches between two non-word characters and two word characters.

```
$str = "1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 2. What is love 1.1? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway";
print_r(preg_split('~(?=\d+\.\B)~', $str,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1. What is love? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway 
    [1] => 2. What is love 1.1? a. Haddaway b. Haxxaway c. Hassaway d. Hannaway
)
```

Comment: thank you for your effort in helping me! thanks to all of you I'm learning and understanding new things!